# How to return 4 - 6% on savings / investments with little / no management?

Tags: investing, savings, investment-strategies, savings-account, europe

What would be the simplest (require the least management) way to get a return of 4 - 6% on savings over a 10 - 15 year period.

I would like the lowest risk possible, I do not need the 'potential' gains to be anything over 4 - 6% but need something that is likely to hit those figures.

I will not need the money as an 'Emergency Fund'.

I would naturally want to pay the least amount of tax possible and do not want to invest in rental properties as that is high maintenance.

I am in Europe and although I don't *think* this will affect the answer, my savings will be in the region of 1,200 - 1,500 euros per month.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: "*way to get a return of 4 - 6% on savings over a 10 - 15 year period.*"  in America, at least, **lots** of people would *kill* for *guaranteed/secure* returns like that over the long term.

Comment: @RonJohn there's no mention of "guaranteed/secure returns" in the question, merely "the lowest risk possible"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm assuming you mean 4-6% annually over 10-15 years.  If you mean 4%-6% total return over 10 years then this question is easy just find your local country's 10Y bond and that should likely cover it (though barely if you are German).

So 4%-6% annually is not a big stretch but it does require some risk and at least a bit of work.  A fire-and-forget good mix would include (using *index* mutual funds or etfs)

- Broad European Stock fund
- Broad ex-European stock fund
- Broad European Bond fund
- Maybe a bit of ex-European bonds and European real estate funds (not actual real estate as you mention it is way too much work)

Some internet research and a one-time meeting with a financial adviser who is paid by you (*not* paid on commission) should help you set the right balance of these index funds and be a good check on what I'm advising.

If you are willing to do a tiny bit more work it's well worth starting with a heavier weight on the riskier stocks and ex-European funds (more currency risk) and then every 2-3 years slowly move into safer stocks and Euro-based funds.  With that tiny amount of extra work there you can make it much more likely that you will end within your 4-6% range while taking significantly less risk overall.

Comment: Some robo-advisors that work in _index_ funds might actually be the easiest way to get the right mix over time (and the fees they charge can be reasonable), but I don't know the robo-advisor space in Europe very well.

Comment: Thanks for the useful answer, I have marked it as the answer. I did mean annually, so thanks for the correct assumption there! The comment against my question seems to disagree with you somewhat, but doesn't provide any evidence, so I will do some real research into Broad European / ex-European Stock funds, as I don't even know what that means at this stage!

Comment: @Cloud I can only guess that that commenter thinks you are looking for a **risk-free** return of 4-6%, which I don't think you are, right?

Comment: @AakashM Risk free? There is no such thing. But low risk, yes.

Comment: @Cloud obviously we are none of us safe from an asteroid destroying human civilisation. Even so, ['risk-free'  is a standard term in investing jargon](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/r/riskfreeasset.asp).

Comment: So what 'Manager Group' would I look at for this broad funds? I'm looking on interactive investor but there are thousands of funds to choose from...

Comment: We generally don't recommend particular managers on this site.  However, you can certainly get answers on how to use int-inv if you ask a separate question.  I've never used the site before myself, but there should be a way to narrow your search to only, say, broad European stock funds that are index funds.